# How to change NODE_ENV when building app with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

I have a `.env` file that contains the `NODE_ENV` variable. Per default, it is set to `development`. When building the React app with webpack, I launch the command `yarn build`:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --open --hot",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production && webpack",
}
```

The `.env`file is:

```js
NODE_ENV = "development"
```

But when logging the `NODE_ENV` value in my webpack configuration file, I can see it is still in `development`. The build is not minified either. But when I write `production` in my `.env` file, everything works fine.

The webpack configuration is:

```js
/* eslint-env node */
const path = require("path");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

const isProductionMode = (mode) => mode === "production";

module.exports = () => {
  const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" });
  const nodeEnv = env.parsed.NODE_ENV;
  console.log(" isProduction", isProductionMode(nodeEnv)) // output: false
  return {
    mode: nodeEnv,
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
      publicPath: "/",
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", "jsx", ".json"],
      alias: {
        api: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/api/"),
        assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/"),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/"),
        containers: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/containers/"),
        data: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/data/"),
        i18n: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/i18n/"),
        models: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/models/"),
        pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages/"),
        routes: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/routes/"),
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
        stores: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/stores/"),
        utils: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utils/"),
      },
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: { loader: "babel-loader" },
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|woff2)$/, use: ["file-loader"] },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            { loader: "babel-loader" },
            {
              loader: "react-svg-loader",
              options: {
                jsx: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      port: 3000,
      inline: true,
      hot: true,
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        favicon: "./src/assets/images/favicon.png",
      }),
      new Dotenv(),
    ],
    optimization: {
      minimize: isProductionMode(nodeEnv),
      minimizer: isProductionMode(nodeEnv)
               ? [new TerserPlugin(), new CssMinimizerPlugin()]
               : [],
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
      },
    },
  };
};
```

The question is thus: how to make sure I can change my `NODE_ENV` when launching the build?

Also, what is the command I should write in my `package.json` to launch the build once the dist folder is uploaded to Netlify or similar hosting platform?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try checking for `process.env.NODE_ENV` instead of `env.parsed.NODE_ENV` if you want to take environment variables passed on the command line into account. These will be exposed as properties on `process.env` - and will take precedence over variables loaded from the .env file there - but not on the `parsed` property of the object returned by `require("dotenv").config()`. These two objects actually are not kept in sync.

You can try this simple node program:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "production"   // simulate command line environment variable
var env = require("dotenv").config()

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)     // output: "production"
console.log(env.parsed.NODE_ENV)      // output: "development"

// .env
NODE_ENV=development
```

Edit: just for completion, just make sure you use the syntax that is right for your OS to set up environment variables on the command line, or use the OS-agnostic `cross-env` package for this purpose.

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "build:dev": "webpack",
  "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack"
},

// .env
NODE_ENV=development

// webpack.config.js
const dotenv = require("dotenv")

dotenv.config()
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)

process.exit(0)

// console output
npm run build:dev      // "development"
npm run build:prod     // "production"
```

Else, as I pointed out in the comment below, you can use the `--node-env` flag to set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable with the webpack CLI.

```
"build:prod": "webpack --node-env=production"
```

Comment: So I've changed the env parsing in webpack by `  const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;;` but `console.log(nodeEnv)` still returns `development` when launching the build command.

Comment: Maybe this is not as straightforward with Webpack as it is with node - haven't done webpack in a while I must say, just remember it being kind of a headache. Reading about it now, it seems that `process.env.NODE_ENV` can be set with the `--node-env` flag when running the webpack CLI. Maybe try that? https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#node-env

Comment: I also found this regarding using environment variables in the webpack config file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449001/how-to-access-env-vars-from-webpack-config-js-file

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Indeed, I had to pass the "env" parameter to the webpack config, delete the NODE_END=xxx in package.json and use directly the flag --node-env production

Comment: Sure. I have just added some more notes to my answer for completion.